# How to abort / rollback a pending postgres transaction using python / psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using python (psycopg2) with pycharm to query data in a postgres data base. I want to abort and rollback a transaction which takes too long. It takes too long because of my missing query writing skills.

I can stop the execution of the python script, but the postgres transaction is still ongoing.

**How to abort / rollback a pending postgres transaction using python / psycopg2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of questions in the above. For the case where you cancel the python script and want to abort the query then:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL

> pg_cancel_backend(pid int)     boolean     Cancel a backend's current query. This is also allowed if the calling role is a member of the role whose backend is being canceled or the calling role has been granted pg_signal_backend, however only superusers can cancel superuser backends.

> pg_terminate_backend(pid int)  boolean     Terminate a backend. This is also allowed if the calling role is a member of the role whose backend is being terminated or the calling role has been granted pg_signal_backend, however only superusers can terminate superuser backends.

Read the full section for all the details. In any case you can use these functions to terminate a query.

For aborting the transaction after a time period I would look at:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html

> statement_timeout (integer)

> Abort any statement that takes more than the specified amount of time. If log_min_error_statement is set to ERROR or lower, the statement that timed out will also be logged. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as milliseconds. A value of zero (the default) disables the timeout.

> The timeout is measured from the time a command arrives at the server until it is completed by the server. In extended query protocol, the timeout starts running when any query-related message (Parse, Bind, Execute, Describe) arrives, and it is cancelled by completion of an Execute or Sync message.

> Setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended because it would affect all sessions.

You could use [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) to set a  value before you ran the query in question.